# Web bluetooth application scanning for manufacturer data

Tags: web-applications, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

I want to create a Web bluetooth application that scan for advertising data (manufacturer data). I used the example provided by chrome [for scaning advertisement](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/scan.html?namePrefix=Ruuvi). However it only gives me the UUIDs of my device and not the manufacturer data.

Do you know if its possible to scan specific device and get their manufacturer data?

Answer (score 2):

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/scan.html?namePrefix=Ruuvi should indeed work and log manufacturer data if broadcasted by the "Ruuvi" BLE device.

Can you see manufacturer data when scanning nearby Bluetooth devices from the internal page `chrome://bluetooth-internals/#devices`? You will need Chrome 92 to see this column *(Chrome Beta at the time of writing)*. See https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/613b3bf2a0de8ac5cddbe73e01b03db20f25d110

If you don't see them, can you try scanning nearby Bluetooth devices with https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp from an Android device? If you still don't see some manufacturer data, it means this device does not broadcast some. If you do, you may be facing a Chrome issue. I'd suggest you file a bug then at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/how-tos/file-web-bluetooth-bugs

Comment: I can see my Ruuvi sensor on the bluetooth internals. However i can not see the manufacturer data unless I connect to them. Sometimes the data pop up for a second and then dissapear it's strange. I can see the manufacturer data on nrf Connect.

Comment: Make sure your Android device is not paired with Ruuvi sensor, and try again with NRF Connect. Can you still see manufacturer data?

Comment: Yes I am not connected to the sensor and I can see the data changing.

Comment: I wonder then if it's a Chromium issue. Please file one as suggested in the answer above.